Recovering data from VM instance that is not booting into recovery mode
I have got Ubuntu (Arm 22.04.03) installed on my VMware Fusion (v13.5.1), on a Macbook M1 Pro. When I boot normally I get this error:

This was caused either after the hard disk became completely full, or after I cleared journal logs to try and free up space (I can't remember in which order, but I suspect it's one of these two things).
When I try to get into recovery mode from GRUB, it doesn't go further than 'EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL unavailable' error:

I don't mind just deleting the VM and installing it again, but there are a couple of files I need to recover. I can't really do it through terminal since I can't get into console through recovery mode.
What other options do I have? Would creating a duplicate VM and then copying over the contents of the .vmdk file (in the VM bundle on my host OS) work? Appreciate any advice.
I would ask this on VMware's community forum but they don't seem to allow new users to create threads...

OK, I have figured it out through some trial and error. After booting, press Esc and boot from the live image (the CD-ROM drive option).
After selecting Try or install Ubuntu, go into terminal and list the partitions using sudo fdisk -l. It will have a device name like /dev/sda1 for example. Then create a mount point for the partition, first creating a directory like sudo mkdir /mnt/my_partition and then mounting to the partition with sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/my_partition.
You can now access the files through terminal ls /mnt/my_partition or by going to Disks in the Utilities folder, selecting the partition and clicking on the link next to 'Mounted at'. That way you can navigate the contents of the partition that contains the files you want to recover.
